# Get Audio levels for 16 and 32 bit recording streams

Tags: c#, naudio

Ive been using [this](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/blob/master/Docs/RecordingLevelMeter.md)

I have tried the second example using float buffer and cannot get that to work as is.  I did try short buffer and divided by the max short and that worked.  so i tried dividing by max float with a float buffer and that didnt work.  Is it my mic capabilities? also is me doing the dividing correct (as its not in the example)?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide us with the code you have attempted this with so we can better help you :)

Comment: "cannot get that to work as is" - is on the OnDataAvailable handler isn't being hit, or it is but you're not getting data, or you are getting data but you're getting the wrong audio level result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with a float buffer as illustrated in the link you posted:

```
void OnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs args)
{
    ...
    var buffer = new WaveBuffer(args.Buffer);
    // interpret as 32 bit floating point audio
    for (int index = 0; index < args.BytesRecorded / 4; index++)
    {
        var sample = buffer.FloatBuffer[index];
        ...
    }
}
```

If what you need is 32-bit integer samples, you need to access the `IntBuffer` field and divide by max int.

```
var sample = buffer.IntBuffer[index] / 4294967296f;
```

Comment: thanks for the response! So the sample i get (let's say with 16bit using the short buffer) is somewhere around 300-1500 depending on input.  so then to get the percent max I imagine i'd need to divide somehow though? to get the 0-1.0 range?

Comment: Yes. You'd want to divide by short MaxValue